# What does Pin type I mean on the ESP32 datasheet

Tags: microcontroller, datasheet, esp8266, pins

On page 3 of the esp32-wroom datasheet ([PDF](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp-wroom-32_datasheet_en.pdf)) it shows a series of pins with type "I".

What does pin type I mean? Are these different to the pin type I/O pins? If so, how?

Comment: It's **I**nput.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy, what does I/O mean?

Comment: @jsotola Hm... One/Zero?? :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. So, undefined or infinity (if you are taking the limit)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some pins can be input and output: I/O (or sometimes General Purpose I/O: GPIO).

Some pins can be outputs only: O.

Some pins can be inputs only: I.

Some pins can be power: P (note that some datasheets will differentiate between input power and ground).

And some pins can be not connected: NC.

Comment: There is a `P` type as well. For **P**ower..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I didn't actually look at the datasheet... I know, for shame.

Comment: Sorry Samuel but I/O is a pin direction type, whereas GPIO is a pin label prefix used by microcontrollers. So they've distinctly different meanings and are not alternative names for the same thing. GPIO1 is the name of pin of type I/O, same as D7 is a pin of type I/O.

Comment: @TonyM No need to be sorry, they're not as mutually exclusive as you seem to imply with "distinctly different meanings". Both are of the direction category which is input/output, so yes, in some cases they are in fact the same thing. All squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares. All GPIOs are I/Os, but not all I/Os are GPIOs.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't implying a point with "distinctly different meanings", I was firmly stating it. GPIO is a pin function and label for microcontrollers but it's not a direction. The General Purpose part describes a pin that a microcontroller's CPU can read or write. Logic chips, memories, FPGAs etc don't have GPIO pins, they have I/O pins. Important not to confuse the two, one's a noun and one's an adjective.

Comment: I stated that you seemed to be implying they're mutually exclusive; there wasn't ambiguity that you were attempting to make "a point", only in what the point was. Do try reading what I wrote one more time. Many devices besides microcontrollers have GPIOs, **including FPGAs**. The initialism 'GPIO' firmly states the direction, it's input/output. Additionally, so you don't get (more?) confused yourself, in the context here the noun is "pin", the adjectives augmenting that noun are "GPIO" and "I/O". Go bother someone else, please.

Comment: I'm sorry to read that discussion or dispute of your answer is considered bothering you. I'll leave you to it. Misleading text still in answer so downvoting.

Comment: @TonyM It's unfortunate that you can't even reply to my points. It's not a discussion in that case, you continue to make obviously incorrect statements directed at a portion of text that has nothing to do with the answer. If it makes your adjective noun feel better, down vote all you want, you're still wrong. If you want to prove that what you stated is anything more than your own misinformed option, then find a citation. Otherwise, that's all it is, your option about a non-critical piece of this correct (and accepted) answer.